# Odd App Delegate Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app delegate, I have multiple NSStrings, declared like so

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *aString;
```

When my view first loads up, the string values are set

```
appDelegate.aString = @"aValue";
```

Where `appDelegate` is

```
self.appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

This all works fine, but for some reason, it does not work on my iPad. It works on the simulator for iPad and iPhone (it is universal) and my iPhone. It was working earlier and I have not messed with it. Whenever I try to access the value after setting it, it returns null. Any ideas on what I should do?

EDIT 1: What I am trying to do is read a property list and if the value is null, I will manually set it like this:

```
if (appDelegate.aString == (id)[NSNull null] || appDelegate.aString.length == 0 ) {
        appDelegate.aString = @"aValue";
}
```

I put a NSLog in the if statement above so I know the code is being executed, but when I try to log aString, it still comes out null, even though I just set it.

I will also add that all the devices are running 4.3.x.

EDIT 2: If I set the value in applicationDidFinishLaunching, it does not come out null, which means there must be a problem setting the value from the view controller. I don't understand why it would not work on just one device though.

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code, is there any additional code that is using aString?

Comment: Edited the OP with more information

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're explicitly using NSNull elsewhere, try using `if (appDelegate.aString == nil || ...` or even just `if (!appDelegate.aString || ...`.

Comment: That's not the problem though. The problem is occurring when I try to set the value of aString using `appDelegate.aString = @"aValue";`

Comment: Have you `@synthesize`d this property?

Comment: Yes, I synthesized all of them

Answer (score 0):

add a method in appdelegate with name

```
- (void) setaString:(NSString*) str{
//add logs and breakpoints here
}
```

Chances are
1. Some thing else is accessing the string.
2. string is being released somewhere.

Comment: I made a function (one like your example, and one with a "_" in front of it) in the app delegate and called it inside the if statement shown above, but nothing shows up in the debugger (device). However, it does work when I run it on the simulator.

Comment: I would say, there is some logical issue in your code. You need to show how are you implementing it.